# Validar labels vacios - Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

soy un poco nuevo en esto de la programacion y estoy con un problemita. Estoy tratando de validar que cuando yo no pongo ningun valor en unos labels me tire un mensaje y no me de error el programa
yo realicé la siguiente funcion:

```
public void verificarVacios(string valorminimo,string valormaximo,string intentos,string resultado)
        {
            if(valorminimo == "" || valormaximo == "" || intentos == "")
            {
                resultado = "No puede estar vacio";
            }
        }
```

y aca la ejecuto:

```
juego.verificarVacios(txtvalorminimo.Text, txtvalormaximo.Text, txtintentos.Text, lblresultado2.Text);
```

Que es lo que está mal? no me valida y me da error el programa

codigo que se ejecuta al presionar boton calcular

```
juego.verificarVacios(txtvalormaximo.Text, txtvalorminimo.Text, txtintentos.Text, lblresultado2.Text);
            juego.intentos = Convert.ToInt32(txtintentos.Text);
            juego.Dado1.valorMinimo = Convert.ToInt32(txtvalorminimo.Text);
            juego.Dado1.valorMaximo = Convert.ToInt32(txtvalormaximo.Text);

            juego.Dado2.valorMinimo = juego.Dado1.valorMinimo;
            juego.Dado2.valorMaximo = juego.Dado1.valorMaximo;

            juego.Dado3.valorMinimo = juego.Dado1.valorMinimo;
            juego.Dado3.valorMaximo = juego.Dado1.valorMaximo;

            for (int i = 0; i < juego.intentos; i++)
            {
                juego.Dado1.tirar();
                juego.Dado2.tirar();
                juego.Dado3.tirar();


                juego.contador++;


                if (juego.Dado1.retonarValor() == juego.Dado2.retonarValor() && juego.Dado1.retonarValor() == juego.Dado3.retonarValor())
                {
                    lblresultado2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                    lblresultado2.Text = "¡¡COINCIDENCIA!! Se necesitaron " + juego.contador + " intentos";
                    juego.contador = 0;
                    juego.intentos = 0;
                    ; break;
                }
                else if (juego.intentos == juego.contador)
                {
                    lblresultado2.Text = "No hay coincidencias";
                    juego.contador = 0;
                    juego.intentos = 0;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: Este: https://i.ibb.co/x6yFbvM/Captura-de-pantalla-2022-10-29-214854.png

Comment: la funcion la estoy ejecutando en la primer linea del boton ejecutar

Comment: creo que me da error porque luego sigue ejecutando el resto y se da cuenta que los campos estan vacios, necesitaria que cuando valide eso se cancele la ejecucion del resto del formulario

Comment: Es por eso, tu error no está en la función que muestras aquí, hay un error en la conversión a entero. Lo mejor es que pongas el código completo

Comment: dale lo paso! edito el post original

Answer (score 1):

Es como dices en los comentarios, tienes que retornan un valor para detener el resto de la ejecución (hay que colocar un if). Para convertir un string en entero lo mejor es ocupar [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0)

Te dejo un ejemplo.

Creo una función para convertir los datos de entrada en entero, esta funciona devuelve 4 valores valores: un booleano que indica si la conversión fue correcta o no, y los 3 valores convertidos

```
public (bool Correcto, int max, int min,int intentos) ConvertInputs(string valorminimo, string valormaximo, string intentos)
{
    int max, min, inten;
    if(int.TryParse(valormaximo, out max) && int.TryParse(valorminimo, out min) && int.TryParse(intentos, out inten)) {
        return (true,max,min, inten);
    }
    return (false,0,0,0);
}
```

Y el resto de tu código queda así:

```
var Datos = ConvertInputs(txtvalormaximo.Text, txtvalorminimo.Text, txtintentos.Text, lblresultado2.Text);

if(Datos.isCorrecto){
  juego.intentos = Datos.intentos;
  juego.Dado1.valorMinimo = Datos.min;
  juego.Dado1.valorMaximo = Datos.max;

  //el resto del código

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes que todo, me gustaría decirte que respetes cada atributo o campo, es decir si es un string o si es un int o un double, etc. El campo valorminimo debe ser entero y el resultado puede ser string. Luego de eso, utiliza en las propiedades de los componentes de .Net, en este caso en las propiedades de los Textbox, puedes seleccionar en la opción TextMode, si es Numero, Texto, Contraseña, etc. Despues te recomendaría en vez usar:

```
if(valorminimo == "" || valormaximo == "" || intentos == "")
        {
            resultado = "No puede estar vacio";
        }
```

utilices:

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valorminimo)  || string.IsNullOrEmpty(valormaximo) || 
 string.IsNullOrEmpty(intentos))
        {
            resultado = "No puede estar vacio";

        }
```

Para validar textos en los Textbox, puedes usar la validación string.IsNullOrEmpty(Txt) que te valida si esta vacío o nulo y finalmente siempre trata de usar bool para saber si los metodos que estas usando hicieron el proceso correcto o falso, para darte una idea de que te esta retornando el método:

```
public  bool verificarVacios(string valorminimo, string valormaximo, string 
 intentos, string resultado)
    {
        bool DatosCorrectos = true;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valorminimo)  || 
  string.IsNullOrEmpty(valormaximo) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(intentos))
        {
            DatosCorrectos = false;

        }

        return DatosCorrectos;
    }


  Valida val = new Valida();

        if (val.verificarVacios("r", "j", "s", "s") == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Todo esta bien");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No pueden estar vacíos");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```